# Create Event in Outlook Calendar using Angular 5

Tags: angular, typescript, outlook

I am using angular version 5.2. I am doing a roombooking portal ,In that I have a requirement I have to add an event to outook calendar for the day on which room has been book.I have a table in which all my booking is listed and on that i have button in every row for adding event in calendar outlook.I have tried with below code:

```
var icsMSG = "BEGIN:VCALENDAR\nVERSION:2.0\nCALSCALE:GREGORIAN\nMETHOD:PUBLISH\nBEGIN:VEVENT\nUID:9832@meetingplanner.io\nDTSTART:" + bookingInfo.StartDate + "\nDTEND:" + bookingInfo.EndDate + "\nDTSTAMP:" + bookingInfo.StartDate + "\nLOCATION: " + bookingInfo.SpaceDescription + "\nSUMMARY: " + bookingInfo.EventDescription + "\nSEQUENCE:0\nTRANSP:OPAQUE\nEND:VEVENT\nEND:VCALENDAR";
window.open("data:text/calendar;charset=utf8," + escape(icsMSG));
```

this was usinng ical js but it is not working in IE.Also in chrome it is giving exception at build time that escape not defined.
Thanks in advance !

Comment: The `escape` function should be avoided https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/escape

Comment: but this does not work on ie browser on chrome it downloads the ics file correctly

Comment: it creates below url which in ie says web page cannot be displayed.SO please let me know if there is any alternative way to do this:
URL :data:text/calendar;charset=utf8,BEGIN:VCALENDARVERSION:2.0CALSCALE:GREGORIANMETHOD:PUBLISHBEGIN:VEVENTUID:9832@meetingplanner.ioDTSTART:2018-11-05T00:00:00DTEND:2018-11-05T00:00:00DTSTAMP:2018-11-05T00:00:00LOCATION: Raum Plenum EmporiaSUMMARY: New EventSEQUENCE:0TRANSP:OPAQUEEND:VEVENTEND:VCALENDAR

Comment: Try `encodeURIComponent` instead

Comment: Can you please explain in detail

Comment: Instead of `escape`, try using `encodeURIComponent(icsMSG)`

Comment: Yes.But my problem is this solution does not work for ie...ics file does not downlloads there..pleaseread comments above

Answer (score 0):

For IE browser instead of window.open I used

```
FileSaver.saveAs(icsMSG, 'filename.ics');
```